# Scala + EclipseLink: JPA annotations treated as abstract traits, cannot be instantiated

Tags: scala, jpa, eclipselink

I am writing a Scala backend which uses EclipseLink as data abstraction layer.

I find I am having problems right out of the box, although several tutorials I have followed indicated no such thing. For example, one of my entities look like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Expose
  @BeanProperty
  protected var id: Int = 0
}

@Entity
class User extends Entity {

  @Expose
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @BeanProperty
  var createdAt: Date

  @Expose
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @BeanProperty
  var updatedAt: Date

  @Expose
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @BeanProperty
  var dateOfBirth: Date

  @Expose
  @BeanProperty
  var twoStepVerificationCode: String

  @Expose
  @BeanProperty
  var firstName: String

  @Expose
  @BeanProperty
  var lastName: String

  @Expose
  @BeanProperty
  var email: String

  @Expose
  @BeanProperty
  var description: String

  @Expose
  @BeanProperty
  var password: String

  @Expose
  @BeanProperty
  var salt: String
}
```

Upon compiling, however, I get a whole set of errors related to the annotations:

```
 Entity.scala:45: trait Id is abstract; cannot be instantiated
   @Id
    ^
 Entity.scala:46: trait GeneratedValue is abstract; cannot be instantiated
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    ^
 User.scala:14: class Entity is abstract; cannot be instantiated
 @Entity
  ^
 User.scala:17: trait Temporal is abstract; cannot be instantiated
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    ^
 User.scala:22: trait Temporal is abstract; cannot be instantiated
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    ^
 User.scala:27: trait Temporal is abstract; cannot be instantiated
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    ^
```

What am I missing, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in Scala a field must be assigned to not be abstract, so just assign your fields to a default-value.

Like this:

```
@Column(name = "external_reference")
var externalReference: Option[String] = None

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
@net.sf.oval.constraint.NotNull
var accountCode: AccountCode = null
```

If you use JPA-2.1 I have some converters which are handy:

```
//// START converters for Option of primitive-types.
/*
Note: They are not autoApply because Scala generates byte-code for Option[java.lang.Object] so EL isn't able to apply them automatically.
 */
@Converter
class OptionLongConverter extends AttributeConverter[Option[Long], lang.Long]{

    def convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: Option[Long]): lang.Long = {
        attribute.map(long2Long).orNull
    }

    def convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: lang.Long): Option[Long] = {
        if (dbData eq null) None
        else Some(dbData)
    }
}

@Converter
class OptionIntConverter extends AttributeConverter[Option[Int], lang.Integer]{

    def convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: Option[Int]): lang.Integer = {
        attribute.map(int2Integer).orNull
    }

    def convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: lang.Integer): Option[Int] = {
        if (dbData eq null) None
        else Some(dbData)
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
@Convert(converter = classOf[OptionIntConverter])
var code: Option[Int] = None
```

For reference-types the converters may be auto-applied:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
class OptionBigDecimalConverter extends AttributeConverter[Option[BigDecimal], JBigDecimal]{

    def convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: Option[BigDecimal]): JBigDecimal = {
        attribute.map(_.bigDecimal).orNull
    }

    def convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: JBigDecimal): Option[BigDecimal] = {
        if (dbData eq null) None
        else Some(dbData)
    }
}

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class OptionStringConverter extends AttributeConverter[Option[String], String] {

    def convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: Option[String]): String = {
        attribute.orNull
    }

    def convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: String): Option[String] = Option(dbData)
}

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class OptionDateTimeConverter extends AttributeConverter[Option[DateTime], Timestamp] {
    def convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: Option[DateTime]): Timestamp = {
        attribute.map(v => new Timestamp(v.getMillis)).orNull
    }

    def convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: Timestamp): Option[DateTime] = {
        Option(dbData).map(v => new DateTime(v.getTime))
    }
}

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class OptionLocalDateConverter extends AttributeConverter[Option[LocalDate], Date] {
    def convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: Option[LocalDate]): Date = {
        attribute.map(v => new Date(v.toDateMidnight.getMillis)).orNull
    }

    def convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: Date): Option[LocalDate] = {
        Option(dbData).map(v => new LocalDate(v.getTime))
    }
}
```

So code like this just works, without needing to specify converter on the mapped-field:

```
@Column(name = "external_reference")
var externalReference: Option[String] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes about your code:

1. You need to define default values for your *var*s (i.e. use an underscore _ ) or they will be *abstract*. Hence, the compiler errors your seeing.
2. Your base class is named *Entity* and it will clash with the JPA's @Entity annotation. Either include the package name or rename you base class to something besides Entity (e.g. MyEntity)

Also, You don't need to use @MappedSuperclass with JPA and Scala; at least not for your example above. You could define your *Entity* as a trait instead of an abstract class:

```
import javax.persistence._

trait MyEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected var id: Int = 0

}
```

Then just mix it in to your JPA Entities.

Here's a simplified User class (For clarity, I left out the other fields and non-JPA annotations):

```
import javax.persistence._
import java.util.Date

@Entity
class User extends MyEntity {

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  var createdAt: Date = _

}
```